# EntityFrameworkCore support for stored procedure

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I am learning dotnet core and trying my hand on EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.I am trying my lab using database first approach, where I want to execute stored procedures which will contain multiple joins. Stored procedures perform read write operation. I am looking for option which is similar to EF6 in botnet 4.5 framework, where we only import stored procedure from DB and entity framework create complex type for DB result.I read multiple articles but none of these has clearly mention that whether EF core support stored procedure or not ,I want to execute mostly complex stored procedure which contains joins etc.
What I found in multiple tutorial is that everyone is importing tables in EFCore but not only complex SP. Any kind of help and suggestion will be very helpful like how to achieve it or any link to article.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and after searching it on internet i have found this resource:
[Execute Stored Procedures In MVC Core Using Entity Framework Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/execute-stored-procedures-in-mvc-core-using-entity-framework-core/)

Now I am able to call complex type SP from EFCore, hope it will help you.

Thanks